# How to force python try run the same iteration again if an exception occurs?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm bulking a list of whatsapp contacts and the case (in a i-th [regarding wap number] iteration into a for loop) whether some element is not loaded until 2 seconds has a special meaning for my program which is not worth tell what that is but when this occurs I cannot send my message for the number regarding the current iteration so I'd try continue but when I do that approach the such number is ignored (since a used continue) and I'd going over and over my list again then I'd ended up getting a lot of unsended messages. I need a way to restart for loop when a exception in webdriverwait occurs to the iteraction which exception was showed up.

Ideal code:

```
for i in numbers:
    try:
       WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.send_message_box_element)))
       send_message()
    except:
        go_back_and_try_again_send_message_to_number_aux()
```

I tried to manipulate the iterator `i` but it doesn't work in python, python just forces `i`  keep going over `numbers`:

```
    for i in numbers:
      try:
        i = aux
        del(aux)##it's necessary
      except:
        pass
       try:
           WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.send_message_box_element)))
           send_message()
       except:
            aux = i
            go_back_and_try_again_send_message_to_number_aux()
```

Comment: You need second, inner loop for that. But be careful to not end up with infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking to repeat the body of the `for` loop util it works, which sounds like the job of a loop:

```
for i in numbers:
    keep_trying = True
    while keep_trying:
        keep_trying = False
        try:
            ....
        except:
            #go_back_and_try_again_send_message_to_number_aux()
            keep_trying = True
```

Comment: how easy it was

Answer (score 1):

Slightly shorter variant of Scott Hunter's answer:

```
for i in numbers:
    while True:
        try:
            ...
        except:
            ...
        else:
            # Only reached if no exception raised
            break
```